# How to access event.target.value from React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I can't access the value of event.target.value from a React child Component, but I can from an HTML tag.

In the example given: it doesn't work for the Button tag (React Component) but works for the button tag (html tag).

```js
import React from "react";
import Button from "./components/Button";

class Calculator extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            topText: "0"
        }
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);

    }

        handleClick(event) {
            this.setState({ topText: event.target.value })
        }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div>{this.state.topText}</div>
                <Button value='1' onClick={this.handleClick}/>
                <button value="2" onClick={this.handleClick}>2</button>
            </div>
        )
}
}

export default Calculator
```

Comment: can you provide the code for `./components/Button`?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have `onClick` on components. They have to be on DOM elements (Eg. `div`, `button`, etc).

Here, `Button` is a component. The solution will be to pass in `onClick` as a prop and attach it to the element in `Button` component.

```js
function Button(props) {
  return <button onClick={props.onClick}>Click Me</button>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have onClick handled inside your button component ? If no thats the reason.

As you are passing onClick props on Button component, So inside Button component.

```
<button  onClick={onClick}/>
```

At the end onClick should be on HTML component only inside Button.

Answer (score 0):

This is because onClick is passed as a prop for the button component. As long as you handle the prop inside the component you should be fine.

This should be inside your button component.

```
render () {
    return <button  onClick={this.props.onClick}/>2</button>;
}
```